# How to display the percentage of the applied tax in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

The problem is simple, the solution doesn't want to meet me. I want to display (echo) the percentage of the VAT I have defined in my woocommerce settings. Let's say it is 24%. I want to echo it (in the cart or checkout page somewhere, it doesn't really matter) as 0.24 . If I change the VAT to 22%, then automatically it should show 0.22 and so on... How can I achieve this?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still interested, this is the solution I found just yesterday afternoon. Create a shortcode using this function:

```
// Function to add shortcode to display tax rates
function woocommerce_template_display_tax() {
global $product;
$tax_rates = WC_Tax::get_rates( $product->get_tax_class() );
if (!empty($tax_rates)) {
    $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates);
    echo sprintf(_x('Price without %.2f %% tax', 'Text for tax rate. %.2f = 
    tax rate', 'wptheme.foundation'), $tax_rate['rate']);
    }
 }
add_shortcode('display_tax', 'woocommerce_template_display_tax');
```

Using the shortcode [display_tax]. It displays actually "Price witout xxx% tax. So, you can modify a bit the code above to just echo the tax amount. Initial code can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788306/woocommerce-output-product-tax-rate-wc-3-0

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty solution in your case is:

```
round( reset( WC_Tax::get_rates() )['rate'] )
```

This will return "24". So this will allow you to do what you want (announce the single shop-wide tax rate), but won't work correctly if your tax settings become more complicated than using just one tax class.

Comment: Thanks pvlr, I found another workaround just yesterday. I created a shortcode.